# ilter chain halted as :logged_in_user rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looked at threads with similar errors, none of which provided me a solution.  Added the following before filter to my `user controller`:

```
 before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:show, :boli, :nolan]
```

And now I get the 'user rendered or redirected message' and can no longer log in.  I'm getting no other errors, any ideas on how to overcome this?

Here is my `session` create code, `session_helper` code and `user_controller` code.

```
def create
  user = User.find(1)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    redirect_to user
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid password'
    render 'new'
  end
end  




module SessionsHelper
  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
   session[:user_id] = user.id
 end

def current_user
 if (user_id = session[:user_id])
   @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif 
   user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?
     log_in user
     @current_user = user
      end
    end
 end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

User Controller Code:

```
  def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
       redirect_to login_url
    end
 end
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
   end


 def log_in(user)
   session[:user_id] = User.find(1)
  end
```

Comment: You should probably add the user id to the session with `log_in` before redirecting in the `create` controller action.

Comment: Just added some code @rossta.  Is that what you're referring to?  If so, it didn't resolve the problem.